# NullPointerException\com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet$CustomerConfiguration.<init>, ephemeralKeySecret

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Error message:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet$CustomerConfiguration., parameter ephemeralKeySecret

my code :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration;
import com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet;
import com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheetResult;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MoneyDonation2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button payment;
    String PublishableKey ="sth";
    String SecretKey = "sth";
    String CustomerId;
    String EphericalKey;
    String ClientSecret;

    PaymentSheet paymentSheet;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.donation_money);
        payment = findViewById(R.id.payment);
        PaymentConfiguration.init(this, PublishableKey);
        paymentSheet = new PaymentSheet(this, paymentSheetResult -> {
           onPaymentResult(paymentSheetResult);
        });

        payment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                getEmphericalKey();
                paymentFlow();
            }
        });
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    CustomerId = object.getString("id");
                    Toast.makeText(MoneyDonation2.this, CustomerId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    getEmphericalKey();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(MoneyDonation2.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + SecretKey);
//                header.put("Stripe-Version", "2022-08-01");
                return header;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
    private void paymentFlow() {
        paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(ClientSecret, new PaymentSheet.Configuration("Learn with OWL", new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                CustomerId, EphericalKey
        )));
    }
    private void onPaymentResult(PaymentSheetResult paymentSheetResult) {
        if(paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Completed) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private void getEmphericalKey(){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/ephemeral_keys", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    EphericalKey = object.getString("id");
                    Toast.makeText(MoneyDonation2.this, EphericalKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getClientSecret(CustomerId, EphericalKey);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(MoneyDonation2.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + SecretKey);
                return header;
            }
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("customer", "CustomerId");
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
    private void getClientSecret(String customerId, String ephericalKey){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    ClientSecret = object.getString("client_secret");
                    Toast.makeText(MoneyDonation2.this, ClientSecret, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(MoneyDonation2.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + SecretKey);
                return header;
            }
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("customer", "CustomerId");
                params.put("amount", "100"+"00");
                params.put("currency", "RM");
                params.put("automatic_payment_methods[enabled]", "true");
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

I'm a newbie who just started android development, I wish to include stripe payment gateway in the project, but i get this error, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split this logic into a [server endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#add-server-endpoint) to create the payment intent (and optional ephemeral key) and then use those values in your client app to [collect payment details](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#android-collect-payment-details).

Note also that when you do have those values, `CustomerConfiguration` should be called with the customer ID and ephemeral key `secret` as shown in the example. Make sure you have valid values for both of those.